# split a sidebar into two

Tags: html, css, menu, split, sidebar

I hope you can all help :)

I have a sidebar on my website but because I don't want it going under the fold I would like to split this ten li sidebar into two 5 li sidebars with a div inbetween them showing content using Jquery. I have coded up the website so it looks good but I need the sidebars to act as one menu instead of two so only one selection can be made at a time , one current class etc. Anyone know how to do this? My mark-up is as follows:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul class="list2"><em>
    <li class="current1"><a href="#tab1">Bilgorajski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Rzeszowski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Kasuby</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Mazur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab5">Lubelski</a></li>
    </em>   
</ul>
</div>

<div id="repcontent">

</div>


<div id="sidebar">
<ul class="list2"><em>
    <li><a href="#tab6">Powislainski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab7">Podhalainski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab8">Kujuwiak Oberek</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab9">Krakowiak</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab10">Szlansk</a></li>
    </em>   
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your markup is wrong: You should not use the same id value more than once in your document. You have used id="sidebar" twice.

Comment: I am quite new to web design and did that in the hope that it would mean its the same menu but alas it didnt work. How would you do it?

Comment: You have `li`s contained within an `em`, which is also invalid.  If you're splitting up your elements because of some archaic idea that users won't scroll to see content below the mythical fold, you're doing it for the wrong reason because users *will* scroll.  Break up the menu because it makes sense content wise, not because of some usability concept that was proven to be flawed 10 years ago.

Comment: I am doing it because of the fold. Just to clarify, i am teaching myself webpage building as a hobby but as a job I am a senior product manager in a large digital company and I can tell you that we have done test upon test and I can say 100% that the fold matters for both conversion rates and usability, I dont know where you have heard otherwise as it is widely known in the industry and has personally increased my business's revenue substantially. Dont mean to rant but its true.

Answer (score 0):

take it easy.. use

```
-webkit-column-count: 2;
```

this will splits your contents into two columns..Or if you want to display the sidebars in two sides separately then use 2 separate divisions and **float:left|right;** property. Or you can query for this using JQuery.

```
    <body>
  <div class="container">
 <div class="sidebar1">
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
</ul>
<p>  </p>
<!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
 <div class="content">

<!-- end .content --></div>
<div class="sidebar2">
<!-- end .sidebar2 --></div>
<!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
```

css

```
  .sidebar1 {
float: left;
width: 20%;
background-color: #93A5C4;
padding-bottom: 10px;
   }
 .content {
padding: 10px 0;
width: 60%;
float: left;
 }
 .sidebar2 {
float: left;
width: 20%;
background-color: #93A5C4;
padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Try this code. this may clarifies your problem .

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I dont understand it fully. I take it I put that in the #sidebar Css but what I dont understand is " if you want to display the sidebars in two sides separately then use 2 separate divisions and float:left|right; property", Could you please elaborate further? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove tags that commented in the following code:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul class="list2"><em>
    <li class="current1"><a href="#tab1">Bilgorajski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Rzeszowski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Kasuby</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Mazur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab5">Lubelski</a></li>
    </em>   
</ul>
<!-- </div> -->

<div id="repcontent">

</div>


<!-- <div id="sidebar"> -->
<ul class="list2"><em>
    <li><a href="#tab6">Powislainski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab7">Podhalainski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab8">Kujuwiak Oberek</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab9">Krakowiak</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab10">Szlansk</a></li>
    </em>   
</ul>
</div>
```

**Edited:** To get three columns layout, I will use [zurb-foundation](/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) CSS framework as follows:

```
<body>
<div id="header" class="row">
 <div class="twelve columns">
Header
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div id="left-sidebar" class="three columns">
   <ul class="list2"><em>
    <li class="current1"><a href="#tab1">Bilgorajski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Rzeszowski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Kasuby</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Mazur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab5">Lubelski</a></li>
    </em>   
   </ul>
  </div>
 <div id="repcontent" class="six columns">
  Middle contents
 </div>
 <div id="right-sidebar" class="three columns">
 <ul class="list2"><em>
    <li><a href="#tab6">Powislainski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab7">Podhalainski</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab8">Kujuwiak Oberek</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab9">Krakowiak</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab10">Szlansk</a></li>
    </em>   
  </ul>

 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I do this I get everything in one column. What I am after is for the first five to be floated left, the second five to be floated right and the "repcontent" to be in the middle. How would you do this?

Comment: So you want three columns layout. Well there are many ways to get three columns layout you are able to search for "Three columns CSS layout" in Google or look at the edit of the answer that uses [tag:zurb-foundation] css framework.